# Using python logging for remote logs

Tags: python, logging

I am using python logging to log my program. All the logs are currently printed on stdout but I want them to be sent to a remote log server using POST REST call. Currently, my program makes multiple POST requests for logging. Is there a more optimized way to send logs where I can bundle multiple logs in single POST request?

```
import logging.handlers

class SumoHTTPHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, url, host="collectors.sumologic.com", name=None, compressed=False):
    """
    Similar to HTTPHandler but with some custom Sumo-friendly headers
    """
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.host = host
        self.url = url
        self.name = name

    def emit(self, record):
        # this is called multiple times. 
        try:
            host = self.host
            h = httplib.HTTPS(host)
            url = self.url
            data = urllib.quote(self.format(record))
            sep = "?"
            url = url + "%c%s" % (sep, data)
            h.putrequest("GET", url)
            h.putheader("Host", host)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            raise
        except:
            self.handleError(record)
```

Comment: Not sure of your exact situation, but, in general bundling multiple log requests in a single request (like batch logging) may not log the true picture. It could be difficult to recover the logs if a batch fails. You may do a *fire and forget* request asynchronously so that application performance is not affected. Depends on your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to reimplement and create your own class. The logging module in python had a HTTPHandler that can be very useful in logging to remote. Here's an example of how you'd do it

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
logger = logging.getLogger('Synchronous Logging')
http_handler = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
    '/log',
    method='POST',
)
logger.addHandler(http_handler)

# Log messages:
logger.warn('Hey log a warning')
logger.error("Hey log a error")
```